# How to load test Aspnetcore.signalr application?

Tags: signalr, load-testing, asp.net-core-signalr

We need to load test aspnetcore signalR application. I saw about crank but that
seems to help only with aspnet signalR. Can someone help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you need a load testing tool which supports [WebSocket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) protocol as this is what SignalR will be doing by default.

It could be also `Server Sent Events`, `Forever Frame` or `Long Polling` so you need to clarify the [NFRs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-functional_requirement) and identify which protocols are in scope and what are the requirements which need to be tested.

Depending on your skills you can go for:

- [Gatling](https://gatling.io/) which has [support of WebSocket](https://gatling.io/docs/current/http/websocket/), but you will need to do some programming in [Scala](https://www.scala-lang.org/)
- [Apache JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/) which supports WebSocket via [the plugin](https://bitbucket.org/pjtr/jmeter-websocket-samplers), JMeter allows you to create tests using simple GUI. You will be able to also test Long Polling and Server Sent Events using JMeter, check out [How to Load Test Async Requests with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-load-test-async-requests-with-jmeter) for more details.